# How to Embed Custom Tradingview Charts in a React Compnent

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a private Tradingview chart that I'm trying to embed in a react app.

So far I tried almost everything on stackoverflow, but still no luck. Here is the embed script;

```
<!-- TradingView Chart BEGIN -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://s3.tradingview.com/tv.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tradingview_embed_options = {};
    tradingview_embed_options.width = '640';
    tradingview_embed_options.height = '400';
    tradingview_embed_options.chart = 'BaYHlVaj';
    new TradingView.chart(tradingview_embed_options);
</script>
<!-- TradingView Chart END -->
```

I tried to use React Helmet, but still couldn't inject the part;

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var tradingview_embed_options = {};
    tradingview_embed_options.width = '640';
    tradingview_embed_options.height = '400';
    tradingview_embed_options.chart = 'BaYHlVaj';
    new TradingView.chart(tradingview_embed_options);
</script>
```

Comment: Have you tried the react-tradingview-widget (https://github.com/rafaelklaessen/react-tradingview-widgetreact)? Though it is not official